# Como colocar un botón o un switch en un ListView

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Quiero saber si es posible colocar un botón o Switch en un ListView. Quiero crear una lista y que en cada elemento de esa lista aparezca un botón o Switch. ¿Cómo  hacerlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Claro que es posible, de hecho cualquier vista personalizada puedes configurarla para que aparezca como elemento dentro de un `ListView`, únicamente tienes que crear una vista personalizada que contenga los elementos que deseas, botón o switch. por ejemplo:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button1" />
    <Switch
        android:text="Switch"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/switch1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Esa vista contendra los elementos que deseas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y esta vista sería la que cargarías en tu adapter, puedes ver este excelente tutorial : **[ListView y Adapter personalizado](http://www.proyectosimio.com/es/programacion-android-listview-adapter-personalizado-i/)**

En este tutorial, nuestra vista reemplazaria `listview_item.xml` cuya vista es inflada en el Adapter.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // En primer lugar "inflamos" una nueva vista, que será la que se
    // mostrará en la celda del ListView. Para ello primero creamos el
    // inflater, y después inflamos la vista.
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);


    // Devolvemos la vista para que se muestre en el ListView.
    return item;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

la manera correcta para insertar un switch es utilizando un **Custom Adapter** con tu **ListView** el cual internamente tiene un método llamado **getView()**

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                         .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false); //En esta linea inflas tu layout
```

}

```
<Linearlayout><Switch></Switch></LinearLayout>
```

Aqui tienes la oportunidad de **inflar** un **layout** que en este caso es **rowlayout**, en ese layout tu puedes insertar los elementos que desees.

Puedes checar este [link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html), aqui te enseñan paso por paso como hacer lo que tu buscas, implementar un **ListView** con un **custom adapter** (Adaptador Personalizado)

Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Si es posible, pero primero debes de especificar que framework estás utilizando para crear el listview, porque básicamente se puede agregar en html con la librería de clases css que utilizan, un ejemplo sería:

```
<ul>
   <li> <– objeto que se va a repetir
      <button onClick="funcionQueLlama()">botón</button>
      <p>Descripción o información del item</p>
      <img href="" /> <– algunos le ponen imágenes y otras cositas
   </li>
</ul>
```

Para ser más específico, yo trabajo con ionic Framework y programo en Angular Js y tiene su propia librería: http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#toggle, bastaría con combinar los elementos para tener el resultado, ej:

```
<div class="list">
   <a class="item item-avatar" href="#"> <– objeto que se va a repetir
     <label class="toggle"> <– switch
       <input type="checkbox">
       <div class="track">
         <div class="handle"></div>
       </div>
     </label>
     <h2>Venkman</h2>
     <p>Back off, man. I'm a scientist.</p>
   </a>
   ...
</div>
```

Comment: Asaf me parece que desea esto pero en Android =( , saludos.

Comment: Hola @Asaf. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so] y gracias por contribuir! Debajo de cada pregunta encontrarás las etiquetas, que sirven para definir el contexto de la pregunta. Probablemente te sea útil realizar el [tour].